# Azure AD B2C - Use CombinedSignInAndSignUp after a ClaimsProviderSelection step

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm creating a custom policy where the user can choose if he wants to signin using a local account or a social account, but instead of showing the local account form in the first page, i want a button to be clicked and then i want to show the form.
When I try to do this using a ClaimsExchange step, everything work as expected.

```
<UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignInCustom">
  <OrchestrationSteps>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsProviderSelection" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.idpselections">
      <ClaimsProviderSelections>
        <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="GoogleExchange" />
        <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
      </ClaimsProviderSelections>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
      <ClaimsProviderSelections>
        <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
      </ClaimsProviderSelections>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
        <ClaimsExchange Id="GoogleExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Google-OAuth2" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    ...
```

If I try to change the second step to CombinedSignInAndSignUp, because I need the user to also have all the signup options, then, when I try to upload the policy, I keep getting this error:

```
An error has occurred during the policies upload: Validation failed: 1 validation error(s) found in policy "B2C_1A_TRUSTFRAMEWORKEXTENSIONS" of tenant "jmontiniteste.onmicrosoft.com".Orchestration step order "2" in user journey "SignUpOrSignInCustom" in policy "B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions" of tenant "jmontiniteste.onmicrosoft.com" is followed by a claims provider selection step and must be a claims exchange, but it is of type "CombinedSignInAndSignUp"Orchestration step order "2" in user journey "SignUpOrSignInCustom" in policy "B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions" of tenant "jmontiniteste.onmicrosoft.com" is followed by a claims provider selection step and must be a claims exchange, but it is of type "CombinedSignInAndSignUp"
```

Is there any way to use a CombinedSignInAndSignUp after a ClaimsProviderSelection step?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
<OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
    <ClaimsProviderSelections>
        <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="GoogleExchange"/>
        <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange"/>
    </ClaimsProviderSelections>
    <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email"/>
    </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>

<!-- Check if the user has selected to sign in using one of the social providers -->
<OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
    <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
            <Value>objectId</Value>
            <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
    </Preconditions>
    <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="GoogleExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Google-OAuth2"/>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail"/>
    </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

Comment: No, this way the form will be shown the first page. I want to have a initial page with 2 buttons: one for local and one for social. If the user clicks on social, then is the normal flow, if the user clicks on local, then I want to show a sign-in form, without the social button below it.